# how to use two different observable arrays knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

What i am trying to do is, from my ajax call get the first result and put it into the `.portfolio--active` div and then remove this first item from the ajax results then loop through the rest of the items in the `.portfolio--active`.

The looping is working perfectly. The problem I am having is with the `.portfolio--active`. I just don't understand how i am meant to output data without it being in a loop or someway of referencing the function name. for example: `<ul data-bind="foreach: items">` reefers to this: `hutber.portfolio.ko.self.items = ko.observableArray([]);` without it being in a l

**Markup**

```
     <section>
    <h2>portfolio</h2>
    <div class="portfolio--active">
        <!--<img alt="" src="/img/clients/vw.jpg">-->
        <img alt="" data-bind="attr: {src: '/img/clients/' + headline.id+'.jpg'}">
        <h3><a href="#">Volkswagen.co.uk</a></h3>
        <date>Febuary, 2012 - <a href="#">Zone Ltd.</a></date>
        <p>Lorem text</p>
        <tags><i title="jQuery" class="icon-rss upsideLeft"></i><i title="jQuery" class="icon-html5 upsideLeft"></i></tags>
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio--options">
        <ul data-bind="foreach: items">
            <li data-bind="attr: {'data-id': $data.id}">
                <img alt="" data-bind="attr: {src: '/img/clients/' + $data.id+'.jpg'}">
                <h4 data-bind="text: title"></h4>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

**JS**

```
hutber.portfolio.ko = {
    init: function(){
        ko.applyBindings(new hutber.portfolio.ko.portfolioViewModel());
    },
    portfolioViewModel: function(){
        hutber.portfolio.ko.self = this;

        hutber.portfolio.ko.self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
        hutber.portfolio.ko.self.headline = ko.observableArray([]);

        $.getJSON('/portfolio/json').done(function(info){

            //build headline item
            hutber.portfolio.ko.self.headline(info.slice(0,1));

            //remove first item in array only leave none headline items
            info = info.slice(1,info.length);

            //update items with updated info
            hutber.portfolio.ko.self.items(info)
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: You should probably try to clarify your question more. Not sure what concept you are struggling with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference the `[0]` index of the array in your bindings, but in your case it seems like maybe you should make `headline` just an observable and just do an `info.shift()` to remove and return the first item in the array to set the value of `headline`. Then, you can just set items as `info` without doing any slicing.

```
    $.getJSON('/portfolio/json').done(function(info){

        //build headline item
        hutber.portfolio.ko.self.headline(info.shift());

        //update items with updated info
        hutber.portfolio.ko.self.items(info)
    });
```